# Is it possible to autogenerate XSD from Java object?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I need to generate XSD file as descriptor of standard. Is it possible to autogenerate XSD from Java object? Of course automated util cannot make complete and fulyl accurate XSD file, but it woild be helpful. So is there any Java libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java6 ships with a tool called `schemagen` (see [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/schemagen.html)) for exactly this purpose. It attempts to generate XML Schema from Java source code.

Comment: Schemagen is part of the Metro JAXB implementation.  The JAXB standard also provides a runtime API for this:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

Comment: Blaise Doughan: thanx for that link, i used that to generate my XSD, sadly you didn't post it as answer...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, off top of my head I can name JAXB and XMLBeans:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Comment: I believe that your links discuss the converse of what the OP is requesting -- yours discuss generating Java classes and interfaces from schema, whereas the OP desires generating schemas from Java classes.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: JAXB provides a means to easily create an XML schema from Java classes: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

Comment: @Hovercraft: I thought it is possible with XMLBeans as well, but it seems that it can generate only xsd from XML documents. So if you're able to get XML from your java somehow, XMLBeans will do but this is a damn hack anyway and you should consider using schemagen instead